# How to tie Sent/Open/Click with Email object

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have connected Sent/Open/Click with their respective job id and subscriber key. I now have to integrate the job id with its job name.

I believe that the job name is same as the name attribute in the Email object. Please correct me if i am wrong.

So, how to map Sent/open/click with the Email object?

Answer (score 0):

Sent, Open, Click all join to the Job dataview on JobID.
See : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sent.htm

So you would use SQL in a similar fashion of :

```
Select 
s.SubscriberKey,
j.EmailName

From _Sent s
Left Join _Job j on s.JobID = j.JobID
```

From Job data view you can get further details of what has been sent/opened/clicked i.e. Email Name, Subject etc.

Comment: I have joined sent open click that is not a problem. I am not sure how to map jobID/sendID with the EmailName. And I want to do this using Soap/REST API so that I can automate through coding.